# Cannot update my knockout bindings with server data

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Warning -- I am very new to knockout. I assume I am doing this all wrong but I feel like I am close.

So my overall goal is to have sample server data come in and bind to that data. I also want to be able to change the data that came in if the user does some action. In this case, they are approving/rejecting items. Right now my example filters out the data on "startup" like I expect it to, but when I try to change an item's accepted/rejected value, my UI doesnt update. So I am struggling with having my UI automatically "re-filter" the data once the user does some action.

Here is my view model currently:

```
function FilterDataViewModel() {
var self = this;

this.data = ko.observableArray(sampleData);
$.each(this.data(), function(idx, item){
    item.myApproved = ko.observable(item.approved);

    item.canApprove = ko.computed(function() {
        return item.myApproved() === undefined;
    });

    item.approve = function() {
        item.myApproved(true);
    };

    item.canReject = ko.computed(function() {
        return item.myApproved() !== false;
    });

    item.reject = function() {
        item.myApproved(false);
    };
});   

self.incoming = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.data(), function(item) {
        return item.approved === undefined;
    });
}, this);

self.accepted = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.data(), function(item) {
        return item.approved === true;
    });
}, this);

self.rejected = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.data(), function(item) {
        return item.approved === false;
    });
}, this);    
  }
```

What feels wrong about that is that I am extending each element in my foreach loop. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Here is my sample data:

```
var sampleData = [{
        "id": "9f86615a-2ec2-43dd-a6a1-99d3a4501969",
        "textData": "Tincidunt accumsan erat delenit nostrud dolor, ullamcorper tincidunt feugait vel feugait, dolor nulla luptatum et. Aliquip, nulla vel commodo aliquam dolore, sit tincidunt nulla dolor blandit, in lorem commodo. Feugait illum, consectetuer dolore tincidunt feugait in, duis aliquip.",
        "approved": undefined,
        "lastUpdatedTime": "2005-05-23T20:39:50 +05:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "141ad8d4-d13e-4887-92ab-8e6785e47c4f",
        "textData": "Aliquip diam odio ut volutpat ex, ut ad nulla blandit lorem, vero aliquam accumsan odio. Nonummy, dolore ut autem erat eros, dolore feugiat et elit volutpat, molestie amet praesent..",
        "approved": false,
        "lastUpdatedTime": "2010-12-12T13:00:54 +06:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "0c84b35c-6cac-4dc7-8798-91a12e27a2ce",
        "textData": "Delenit erat dolore vel ut accumsan, ad feugiat quis consequat laoreet, volutpat hendrerit feugiat nibh. Ea, hendrerit ad exerci commodo nostrud, sit vel in at elit, magna ullamcorper consequat. Wisi sit, laoreet odio consequat nisl ipsum, euismod minim consequat magna tincidunt, eros duis..",
        "approved": true,
        "lastUpdatedTime": "1993-08-20T22:14:50 +05:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "8a29682f-0b90-427f-9627-036dbe2f0191",
        "textData": "Zzril accumsan nonummy duis hendrerit eu, tincidunt nibh ea in nostrud, minim vel consectetuer consectetuer. Augue, nisl qui ipsum erat vel, odio eum.",
        "approved": true,
        "lastUpdatedTime": "1994-10-10T02:06:48 +05:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "461dab99-5ac7-4e31-8c56-b7703af050d0",
        "textData": "Nonummy dolor laoreet in exerci ut, ut ea hendrerit ut at, zzril exerci iusto ullamcorper. Nostrud, nisl nulla in facilisis luptatum, facilisis augue.",
        "approved": true,
        "lastUpdatedTime": "1997-04-10T05:18:15 +05:00"
    }];
```

Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Travyguy9/j3WTN/

I tried to use the ko.mapping.fromJS to generate the viewmodel straight off the data coming in but that never seemed to properly create an object so I went away from that.

To reiterate -- Id like to read in that sample data and filter it out and then let the user change some values and when they do, id like my UI to re-filter the data.

Also, approved is a 3 state: undefined is untouched, true is approved, false is rejected

UPDATE -- I did get it to work by making my incoming/accepted/rejected computed values use 'myApproved' and not just 'approved'. I still wonder if there is a better way to "extend" the server data.

Comment: You mean you are trying to get the objects to move to the correct tab after a selection has been made?

Comment: Yea. Basically the user is marking an item to be under a new tab.

Comment: Are you doing this for a tutorial or do you want to rework the code?

Comment: Im trying to teach myself knockout. I went with a guess on how to write the viewmodel and I feel like I went down the wrong path. It seems wrong to foreach and extend the data to have new observables and computed methods. So I am assuming the code will need reworked, but maybe not. I am not following any tutorial at all, just trying different things that I could do with knockout.

Comment: Ok cool.  I am going to play with it a bit but you are correct in that you should not need to iterate through the data.